# Distinguishing number values vs string values when looping istringstream

Tags: c++

So if someone enters a sentence for example: "25 Hello World 5.9 Again" how do I differentiate between a number and a string when looping through the istringstream? The random sentence string will be entered and captured via getline(). What I am trying to accomplish is to break apart the entered string on the white space and then cout the individual words and numbers in their own line but if it is a number, multiply the number by 2 before cout.

Thanks!

Example:

```
string input;
cout << "Please Enter A Sentence: ";

getline(cin, input);
//So string input say has the value now of "Hello world, there are 3.5 items."
```

And after processing the final output would look like this:

```
Hello
world,
there
are
7
items.
```

Comment: You can use `std::istringstream` to break the line in parts, and `std::stoi()` to check if a part is a number.

Comment: must code byself, get (unknown before!) line, analyse etc...

Comment: Use strtok() or similar